# Problems with changing register in nebular auth ngx-admin

Tags: html, angular, typescript, nebular, ngx-admin

I'm trying to do custom register form with custom inputs such as 'First Name' and 'Last Name', instead of 'Full name'. But when I've created custom notifications whose start working on switching focus on background or another input, there must appear 'First Name is required!' and etc. These things doesn't work.

[image: image here]

Code:

```
div class="form-control-group">
    <label class="label" for="input-name">First name:</label>
    <input nbInput
           [(ngModel)]="user.name"
           #name="ngModel"
           type="text"
           id="input-name"
           name="name"
           placeholder="First name"
           fullWidth
           fieldSize="large"
           [status]="name.dirty ? (name.invalid  ? 'danger' : 'success') : 'basic'"
           [required]="getConfigValue('forms.validation.name.required')"
           [minlength]="getConfigValue('forms.validation.name.minLength')"
           [maxlength]="getConfigValue('forms.validation.name.maxLength')"
           [attr.aria-invalid]="name.invalid && name.touched ? true : null">
    <ng-container *ngIf="name.invalid && name.touched">
      <p class="caption status-danger" *ngIf="name.errors?.required">
        name is required!
      </p>
      <p class="caption status-danger" *ngIf="name.errors?.minlength || name.errors?.maxlength">
        name should contain
        from {{ getConfigValue('forms.validation.name.minLength') }}
        to {{ getConfigValue('forms.validation.name.maxLength') }}
        characters
      </p>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
```